# Change URL to filepath

Tags: sed, awk

I want to generate a file path based on URL path. The following is the URL and I want to change it to the one given below.

```
myurl="https://reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/"

/home/shantanu/company/reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/
```

The first two (/home/shantanu/) is my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed,

```
sed 's_https://_home/shantanu/company/_g'
```

Example:

```
$ myurl="https://reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/"
$ echo $myurl | sed 's_https://_home/shantanu/company/_g'
myurl="https://reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/"
```

Answer (score 0):

In AWK you may do:

```
BEGIN {
     myurl="https://reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/";
     sub("https:\/\/","\/yourdir\/whatever\/",myurl);
     print myurl;
}
```

Result:

```
/yourdir/whatever/reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/
```

[Running on ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/FKscu)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/https:\//\/home\/shantanu\/company/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myurl="https://reports.company.com/users/clients/Daily/MonFile/"
echo "$myurl" | sed "s|https\?://\([^.]*\.\)\([^.]*\)\(\.*\)|$HOME/\2/\1\2\3|"
```